# OpenGL and Delphi - draw png image (D2 texture)

Tags: delphi, opengl, png, textures

I'm not an able to load png image into 2D texture and draw that on the form.

I need to draw very fast a lot of transparent png images, that I cut from a larger png image, on prepared background and then show that on the screen.

I don't want to use any controls and trying to avoid external libraries if that's possible. Just to use Pngimage from Delphi and OpenGL unit.

I was able to draw the bitmap image on a form and here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.InitOpenGL;
var
  PixelFormat: GLuint;
  pfd: TPixelFormatDescriptor;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@pfd, SizeOf(pfd));
  pfd.nSize := SizeOf(pfd);
  pfd.nVersion := 1;
  pfd.dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
  pfd.iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
  pfd.cColorBits := 32;
  pfd.cDepthBits := 24;
  pfd.iLayerType := PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

  hdc := GetDC(Handle);
  PixelFormat := ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, @pfd);
  SetPixelFormat(hdc, PixelFormat, @pfd);

  hrc := wglCreateContext(hdc);
  wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  glGenTextures(1, @renderImage);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderImage);

  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmp.LoadFromFile(imageFilename);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bmp.ScanLine[bmp.Height - 1]);
  finally
    //bmp.Free;
  end;

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawScene;
var
  imageWidth, imageHeight: Integer;
begin
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Get the width and height of the image
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderImage);
  glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, @imageWidth);
  glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, @imageHeight);

  // Translate the quad to the center of the form
  glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

  // Draw the quad with the adjusted vertices
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(-bmp.Width/Form1.Width, -bmp.Height/Form1.Height);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(bmp.Width/Form1.Width, -bmp.Height/Form1.Height);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(bmp.Width/Form1.Width, bmp.Height/Form1.Height);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(-bmp.Width/Form1.Width, bmp.Height/Form1.Height);
  glEnd;

  SwapBuffers(hdc);
end;
```

But the code for ping is not working. In some attempts I was able to get something on the screen (random pixels a few lines) but I'm stuck. Png image is created in Gimp.

Here is the code.

```
procedure TForm1.InitOpenGL;
var
  PixelFormat: GLuint;
  pfd: TPixelFormatDescriptor;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@pfd, SizeOf(pfd));
  pfd.nSize := SizeOf(pfd);
  pfd.nVersion := 1;
  pfd.dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
  pfd.iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
  pfd.cColorBits := 32;
  pfd.cDepthBits := 24;
  pfd.iLayerType := PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

  hdc := GetDC(Handle);
  PixelFormat := ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, @pfd);
  SetPixelFormat(hdc, PixelFormat, @pfd);

  hrc := wglCreateContext(hdc);
  wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  glGenTextures(1, @renderImage);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderImage);

  png := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    png.LoadFromFile('image.png');
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, png.Width, png.Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, png.AlphaScanline[png.Height - 1]);
  finally
    png.Free;
  end;
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawScene;
var
  imageWidth, imageHeight: Integer;
begin
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Get the width and height of the image
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderImage);
  glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, @imageWidth);
  glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, @imageHeight);

  // Translate the quad to the center of the form
  glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

  // Draw the quad with the adjusted vertices
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(-png.Width/Form1.Width, -png.Height/Form1.Height);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(png.Width/Form1.Width, -png.Height/Form1.Height);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(png.Width/Form1.Width, png.Height/Form1.Height);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(-png.Width/Form1.Width, png.Height/Form1.Height);
  glEnd;

  SwapBuffers(hdc);
end;
```

Now I'm not getting any errors but nothing is drawn.

Comment: PNG data has the first scanline first, not the last scanline

Comment: Also, it seems to me like you are only uploading the alpha channel to the graphics card (I suppose `AlphaScanline` gives you a pointer to contiguous decompressed alpha values -- if so, you are lying when you claim this to be `GL_RGBA`. It's only the `A` part.). Further, I don't remember how the fixed pipeline handles alpha-transparent textures. (In the programmable pipeline, you can of course do precisely what you want to do, like I do here: https://algosim.org/SynViewSource/rgl.html)

Comment: https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

Comment: "PNG data has the first scanline first, not the last scanline"? I don't undestand this.

Comment: Thakk you Andreas. I've found the last link but wasn't able to solve it. When I create images in Gimp, I see RGBA. I've played with this image (manually cutting parts of the image) and I'm sure that the alpha is present. Here is a problem that algorithm that is getting RGB values probably not work OK.

Comment: @brane: A typical BMP file stores its pixels in a contiguous sequence of RGB triples (bytes) in row major order, but with the last row first. @user is saying that the PNG buffer has the first row first, implying that the BMP-style `png.AlphaScanline[png.Height - 1]` is wrong and should be `png.AlphaScanLine[0]`. The first pixel is the first pixel of the first line, not the first pixel of the last line as in a BMP. That's what @user is trying to say.

Comment: You need to send the uncompressed pixels to the graphics card. So you need to have all your pixels in a contiguous RGBA array in your computer's RAM (px[0].r, px[0].g, px[0].b, px[0].a, px[1].r, px[1].g, px[1].b, px[1].a, ...) and then send a pointer to this block of memory to OpenGL. So the first thing you need to do is to make such a block of memory. I don't know much about the `TPngImage`, but it seems like the docs state that `png.AlphaScanLine[y]` is a ptr to a block of only alpha values.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is the code that draws the png image or part of the image on the form from desired points (top left corner). It uses only Delphi and OpenGL. For now it uses fixed pipelines and I'll try to switch to shaders but this great progress for me now.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Winapi.OpenGL, PngImage;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FGLContext: HGLRC;
    FTexture: GLuint;
    FPngImage: TPngImage;
    procedure InitOpenGL;
    procedure LoadTexture;
    procedure DrawTexture(width, height, texWidth, texHeight, texOffsetX, texOffsetY, offsetX, offsetY: single);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TRGBA = packed record
    R, G, B, A: Byte;
  end;

  PRGBA = ^TRGBA;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InitOpenGL;
  FPngImage := TPngImage.Create;
  FPngImage.LoadFromFile('image.png');
  LoadTexture;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FTexture <> 0 then
    glDeleteTextures(1, @FTexture);
  FPngImage.Free;
  wglDeleteContext(FGLContext);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DrawTexture(100, 49, 250, 180, 70, 50, 10, 15);
end;

procedure TForm1.InitOpenGL;
var
  pfd: TPixelFormatDescriptor;
  pf: Integer;
  glc: HGLRC;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@pfd, SizeOf(TPixelFormatDescriptor));
  pfd.nSize := SizeOf(TPixelFormatDescriptor);
  pfd.nVersion := 1;
  pfd.dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
  pfd.iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
  pfd.cColorBits := 24;
  pfd.cDepthBits := 32;
  pf := ChoosePixelFormat(Canvas.Handle, @pfd);
  SetPixelFormat(Canvas.Handle, pf, @pfd);
  glc := wglCreateContext(Canvas.Handle);
  wglMakeCurrent(Canvas.Handle, glc);
  FGLContext := glc;

  // Enable blending
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);

  // Set the blend function to take alpha into account
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadTexture;
var
  PixelData: PByte;
  Pixel: PRGBA;
  x, y: Integer;
  Color: TColor;
begin
  // Allocate memory for the texture data
  GetMem(PixelData, FPngImage.Width * FPngImage.Height * SizeOf(TRGBA));
  try
    // Copy the PNG image data into the texture data
    Pixel := PRGBA(PixelData);
    for y := 0 to FPngImage.Height - 1 do
    begin
      for x := 0 to FPngImage.Width - 1 do
      begin
        Color := FPngImage.Canvas.Pixels[x, y];
        Pixel^.R := GetRValue(Color);
        Pixel^.G := GetGValue(Color);
        Pixel^.B := GetBValue(Color);
        Pixel^.A := FPngImage.AlphaScanline[y]^[x];
        Inc(Pixel);
      end;
    end;

    // Create and bind the texture object
    glGenTextures(1, @FTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FTexture);

    // Set the texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Load the texture data into the texture object
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, FPngImage.Width, FPngImage.Height, 0,
      GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, PixelData);

    // Enable texturing
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  finally
    FreeMem(PixelData);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawTexture(width, height, texWidth, texHeight, texOffsetX, texOffsetY, offsetX, offsetY: single);
begin
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FTexture);

  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(-1 + (offsetX / Form1.Width * 2.0) + (width / Form1.Width), 1 - (offsetY / Form1.Height * 2.0) - (height / Form1.Height), 0.0);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(texOffsetX / texWidth, (texOffsetY + height) / texHeight); glVertex2f(- width / Form1.Width, - height / Form1.Height);
    glTexCoord2f((texOffsetX + width) / texWidth, (texOffsetY + height) / texHeight); glVertex2f(width / Form1.Width, - height / Form1.Height);
    glTexCoord2f((texOffsetX + width) / texWidth, texOffsetY / texHeight); glVertex2f(width / Form1.Width, height / Form1.Height);
    gltexCoord2f(texOffsetX / texWidth, texOffsetY / texHeight); glVertex2f(- width / Form1.Width, height / Form1.Height);
  glEnd;

  glFlush;
  SwapBuffers(Canvas.Handle);
end;

end.
```

Desired parameters for texture and start point for drawing are passed as parameters in the call to the procedure DrawTexture.

I hope that this can be a starting point for someone that just starts to use OpenGL.

Comment: I've one issue with this code. The rest of the form is painted in green (or color which I choose as clearColor). On the form I'll have a background image so I want that excepet area where texture is drawn the rest of the form stays intact.